# Find if a nonblank cell range contains either the same value or multiple values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I find if a nonblank cell range contains either the same value or multiple values?

I tried the below formula and it worked. so I thought I might share it with everyone.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:10,A1)>COUNTIF(A2:A10,"?*")
```

^Second CountIf is formulated this way in case the cell is not true blank. Alternatively, use COUNTA instead.